# Where can the security rooms spawn on The Diamond heist?

Tags: payday-2

Where are the possible spawn locations for the Security (ie Camera) room in The Diamond.  I've seen in the maintenance rooms in the Lower Hall (see image below).  Can the Security Room be in any of the Maintenance Rooms on any floor?

[image: Lower Hall]

[image: Main Hall]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Payday 2 wikipedia, the cameraroom can be behind any of the white doors.

> The location of the numerous white metal doors remains constant, however, their contents change between attempts:
>
> - Doors with a red and white "Employees Only" sign are empty, but can be used to stash bags or evade patrols.
> - Doors with a orange and black electrical danger sign above them contain an electric box.
> - Doors with a black and white "Security" sign contain the camera system, a security guard, and the security computer.

http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/The_Diamond